# iOS - UIAlertController hidden under keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, uialertcontroller

I have an `UIAlertController` presented from a `UIViewController` which is pushed in the `UINavigationController` as the last `UIViewController`. This `UIAlertViewController` has a `UITextField` in it.

My problem is that when I select the `UITextField` the keyboard shows up, but the `UIAlertViewController` stays centered, and partly hidden under the keyboard.

My code looks like this:

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Your PIN" message:@"Please enter your PIN!" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
        [textField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
    }];

UIAlertAction* okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Confirm"
                                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {  }];


UIAlertAction* cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                           style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                                                         }];
[alert addAction:okAction];
[alert addAction:cancelAction];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Screnshot**[image: Hidden UIAllertController]

Comment: this is in simulator or in a real device?

Comment: real device, with latest iOS

Comment: Can't reproduce based on the info you've given. Perhaps it has something to do with _when_ that code runs (i.e. the context). But you have not shown that.

Comment: do you have any messages like "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController>”?

Comment: Try presenting your alert-controller with delay of 0.5 or 1 sec.

Comment: I suggest to hide keyboard when you are using `UAlertController`. Or use a custom alertcontroller.

Comment: I have exact the same problem with the following scenario: 1). Present UIAlertViewController as described above. This works OK. 2). Deactivate the app, for example by opening another app. 3). Reactivate the app. The keyboard is gone, and has the be reactivated again by tapping on the text field. Now the dialog is presented under the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyboard is presented in a dedicated window. So is an alert, your viewcontrollers (see you application delegate's `window` property) etc. It is the `windowLevel` of `UIWindow` instances that determine the z-order of the windows (i.e. how windows are presented above/below each other).

We have seen the same behaviour in our app where we use a custom window for custom alerts, which is always shown below the keyboard's window. It seems like window level behaviour has changed at some point during iOS 9/10 releases, so that the keyboard's window is always at the top of the window stack.

Since `UIAlertController`'s window is managed by the system, there is likely no way for 3rd party developers to modify this behaviour.

To inspect the window level of the alert's window, however, you can reference its `view`'s `window`'s `windowLevel` property after you have presented it (eg in the presentation function's completion block). Perhaps even change it to a very large value in an attempt to force the alert's window level.

To track this issue you could duplicate [this radar](http://www.openradar.me/22715674).

Answer (score 5):

It should be automatically be adjusted.
Check you view hierarchy

Comment: beatrob, I have tried your code without any changes and it adjust automatically as "cjay" said

Comment: Works fine as is. No changes needed. May be a bug with iOS.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you, the problem is that alert is shown under keyboard. I think the problem is that the UIAlertController is shown on your viewController? but the keyboard is shown from rootViewController. Try this code to manage the problem

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: NSLocalizedString("Message", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in }
alert.addAction(okAction)
let rootViewController: UIViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last!.rootViewController!
rootViewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I wrote extension, because in some cases the code above could not work

```
extension UIApplication {

class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(base: nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        let moreNavigationController = tab.moreNavigationController
        if let top = moreNavigationController.topViewController, top.view.window != nil {
            return topViewController(base: top)
        } else if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(base: selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(base: presented)
    }
    return base
}
```

}

usage

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString(title, comment: ""), message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    UIApplication.topViewController()?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: It did not work for me. I guess that this should be an iOS's bug.

Comment: answer edited, please, try it, in my case works perfectly

Comment: have you checked returned value of topViewController?

Answer (score 0):

I concluded that this should a bug of iOS, so I decided to handle it by creating a normal UIView. Here is a .xib file that I created for mocking UIAlertcontoller with UITextField in it. Hope your time will be saved some at least.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kg2nf9qcm4flhk0/AlertviewWithTextield.xib?dl=0

Answer (score -1):

You can add `[self.view endEditing:YES];` to be sure the keyboard won't be show.

Comment: How would someone enter their PIN in this box without a keyboard?

Answer (score -3):

```
You can manage your keyboard based on textField location.


// Call this method somewhere in your view controller in **viewdidload** method

    - (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

    }

//Add in your View Controller which Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.

    - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
    {
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

        // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
        // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
        CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
        aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
        if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
            [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:activeField.frame animated:YES];
        }
    }
// Add in your View Controller which Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent

    - (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
    {
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    }

Initialize UITextField * activeField;

Additional methods for tracking the active text field.

    - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        activeField = textField;
    }

    - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        activeField = nil;
    }
```

You can also check these concept in apple documents.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html